# WP: Create multiple taxonomy archives from the same tax and link term links to them based of the unique query the term is listed in

Tags: taxonomy, relation, wordpress

I have a CPT called "Clinical Trials." There are three taxonomies associated with "Clinical Trials" —"Locations", "Cancer-Types", and "Status". I have a query set up to return a list of all "Cancer-Types" terms, ONLY if they contain posts with the term "current-trial" from the "Status" taxonomy associated. Now, those terms link to the cancer-type-taxonomy archive page. I have modified the archive query to only return the current queried object if the term "current-trial" from the "Status" taxonomy is associated with the posts.

Now I need to repeat this process for the taxonomy "Status”, term "completed-trial". Generating the list of terms is easy, however the terms link back to the cancer-type archive page which is already modified to only return  posts associated with the "Status" term "current-trial".

I need to create a second archive page for "cancer-type" that only returns posts associated with the “completed-trial" term from the "Status" taxonomy. 
How can I have two unique taxonomy pages based off of the same taxonomy and link all term links for that taxonomy to it based on the new query.

Comment: You may find an answer in the wordpress stackexchange site